# UFW Issues (internal vpn vs device vpn)

Tags: vpn, ufw

I have a device with UFW enabled to allow local traffic and tun0 traffic only and it works great from my local devices but when I try to connect from a device that is on my VPN (VPN on local network not this device) it does not work and gets blocked.
I reset my UFW and did it over yesterday but without success it still block the connection.

To make it clear my device is connected to a VPN of its own (external supplier) and UFW forces traffic over it or blocks it, and my phone (for example) when on my own VPN to access my internal network I cannot access this device....unless I run "killall openvpn" and terminate the devices VPN connection.

It's very odd as I don't understand the correlation between UFW blocking internal traffic (home network VPN range) until tun0 is terminated....

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is an example of the setup:

[image: Network Diagram]

1. the green line is internal network connections (no issues here)
2. the orange line is external to home VPN (issue with this connection)
3. the yellow line is device VPN to internet (no issues here)

Thanks,

--Phil

Comment: I believe that is by design that way.  VPNs running at the device level are designed that way to not allow its traffic on the local network.  If it did, then everyone could see your traffic if you were at a coffee house or somewhere that has an open network for all to join thus creating a massive security breach.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I have two VPNS.
The device that I cannot access when I am remotely connected to my home network via my home network VPN is itself connected to a VPN (external VPN). When I am home (10.10.11.0/24) I can connect to it fine, but when on my VPN to home (172.16.1.0/24) I cannot, but both ranges are allowed in on UFW. It only works when I turn off openvpn on the device (while my computer/phone is still remotely connected), but UFW is still running....

Comment: I am really having a hard time following what you are saying, because in your question you state "I try to connect from a device that is on my VPN (VPN on local network not this device) it does not work and gets blocked".  Are you only having issues externally, or on your local LAN as well?  However, one thing that I can think of is not having proper routing being pushed to the external devices so that they can see your internal network systems by adding a line like `push "route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0"` to your `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf` file.

Comment: When I am home I can access the device fine, when I go out and remote in via my home VPN server I cannot connect to the device. I added a picture to help explain in the main post. The device in question uses a VPN to make outward connections.

Comment: Do you have port 1194 UDP forwarded to your OpenVPN server through your router?

Comment: My router is a Unifi USG-Pro-4, the VPN is on that device and it works properly as I can access all my other computers, my server, and devices. However I have 4 of these issue devices with UFW that are connected to the internet with a different VPN (they are at home so obviously not connected to the home VPN) and ALL have the same issue. I have another linux server I can SSH into without issue when I am remotely VPN connected to my home network but it does not use VPN connectivity or UFW.